# OOCSS - only use class to do styling

Tags: css, oocss

I am practicing OOCSS now but I meet a problem.

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

If I want to style these 3 `<li>` items separately I will do:

```
li:nth-of-type(1) {}
li:nth-of-type(2) {}
li:nth-of-type(3) {}
```

But according to OOCSS we should use class to style the elements, like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="li-1">a</li>
    <li class="li-2">b</li>
    <li class="li-3">c</li>
</ul>

.li-1 {}
.li-2 {}
.li-3 {}
```

Now seems OK but what if I have 10 `<li>` I have to add 10 classes which looks dumb to me.

Which style should I use? Can I use those that other than classes to style the elements, based on OOCSS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, technically I think what they are referring to is that you should use classes instead of html element identifiers.

So perhaps doing something like:

```html
<ul>
   <li class="li">a</li>
   <li class="li">b</li>
   <li class="li">b</li>
</ul>
```

And then just use your original styles like:

```css
.li:nth-of-type(1) {}
.li:nth-of-type(2) {}
.li:nth-of-type(3) {}
```

In your case you're basically using classes as you would use an id. Classes are supposed to identify multiple elements.